# Facebook Like URL data Extract using python

Tags: python, facebook, url

I am trying to implement facebook like feature, ie, if you give a url, it extract data such as images, title and description. I know people have done it using php, jquery and ajax (http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/) and some more also.

But because of some reasons I want to do it in python. But I am totally clueless how to start. Please help and give pointers to get started.

Comment: What was wrong with your old post?

Comment: meaning, which old post ??

Comment: Sorry. Someone just decided to ask exactly the same question today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836500/how-to-generate-preview-of-a-url-on-html-form-using-python

Comment: @Shweta https://github.com/ludbek/webpreview